# Animate a UILabel and UIButton within a single UIView.transition block?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, uilabel

I need to animate the change of the value of a UILabel and a UIButton's image property.

I currently use two UIView.transition blocks which seem to work fine, but it seems awful and Im sure theres a far better way Im missing to avoid having duplicated code. Currently doing this:

```
UIView.transition(with: label, duration: 1, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
        self.label.text = someText
}, completion: nil)

UIView.transition(with: aButton, duration: 1, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
        self.aButton.setImage(aUIImage, for: .normal)
}, completion: nil)
```

Afaik theres no init for UIView.transition which takes in an array of UIViews to animate or something similar.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need to specify `.allowAnimatedContent` if you also want animations in the block? Does it actually work without it?

Comment: Hmm it works fine without that. Yes.

Comment: Actually, what’s awful about this? I get that the options argument is duplicated, but you are doing different things in the closure, so how do you imagine that this can be improved at all? Can you show what kind of code that you are expecting to achieve, even if it is just pseudocode?

Comment: Hmm I was under the impression that UIView.transition would have an initializer that would receive an array of UIViews or something similar in order to apply the same animation to multiple views instead of just a single one.

Comment: I believe you can specify the superview shared by both and it will animate both in one block.

Answer (score 0):

#### Concept

Looks like there are no 'built-in' ways to transition multiple views within one `UIView.transition` animation block.

Instead, we can try to make our own if we had a way to control transitions without blocks. Enter `CATransition`!

You can use `CATransition` to add cross-dissolve effects to `CALayer` like so:

```swift
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.3
transition.type = .fade
view.layer.add(transition, forKey: "transition")
```

#### Answer

`CATransition` objects can be added to multiple layers at the same time. So we can use this knowledge to write our own code that applies this transition to multiple layers (or views) at the same time.

I went ahead and made a `UIView` extension for you. The stripped down version looks like this:

```swift
extension UIView{

    class func groupTransition(
        with views: [UIView],
        duration: TimeInterval,
        animations: (() -> Void)?
    ){
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = duration
        transition.type = .fade
        
        for v in views{
            v.layer.add(transition, forKey: "transition")
        }
        
        animations?()
    }
}
```

You can pass the list of views you want to transition and perform all the transition changes in a single block.

```swift
UIView.groupTransition(
    with: [label, aButton],
    duration: 0.3
) {
    self.label.text = self.getRandomText()
    self.aButton.setImage(self.getRandomImage(), for: .normal)
}
```

#### Discussion

I added some more functionality (like animation curve, delay, etc.) and made a more usable version of this and posted it here.

- https://github.com/Thisura98/uiview-group-transition/blob/main/transitiontest/UIView%2BTransition.swift

Of course there are disadvantages with this approach. You lose all the fancy transitions built in such as the "flip" transition. This is because the CoreAnimation Transition API only has some basic (but nice) effects baked in.

Feel free to fork the repo and tweak it for your liking.